# Copy pwd straight from keyboard

Tags: terminal

I looked for a way to copy the current straight to the keyboard and found it in another topic. Now I have in my .bash:

```
alias pwd='pwd | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

but when now when I type the command, it directly execute it. So for example if I type:

```
cp -r <Command-V>
```

it directly reads in my command without me being able to add anything after it. How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Your alias looks odd. Shouldn't you have double quotes around the whole thing?

Comment: mhm no, this works for all my aliases. I am working on a mac OS X, 10.7.5